# List All the Kafka connect workers running in a group in distributed mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to list all the Kafka connect workers running in a single group in distributed mode.
My use case is that if a workers closes/killed due to any reason, I could recreate the worker to join again to that group. Also, all the workers will be running on different machines on a network. Therefore, I need to have a central logging of all the available workers in a group.

But, I couldn't find a way to list all the workers ( The leader node and the follower nodes). could somebody tell how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

When a worker leaves, or joins, a Kafka Connect cluster the tasks get [rebalanced](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-415%3A+Incremental+Cooperative+Rebalancing+in+Kafka+Connect) automatically. Therefore you should only need to monitor the Kafka Connect worker processes in isolation on each host machine and restart it if you see a failure.

You can find out which workers are currently executing a connector's tasks using the [REST API](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-connect/rest-api/#inspecting-task-details):

```json
$ curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors?expand=info&expand=status" | jq '.'

   "status": {
      "name": "source-datagen-01",
      "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "kafka-connect-03:8083"
      },
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "state": "RUNNING",
          "worker_id": "kafka-connect-03:8083"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "state": "RUNNING",
          "worker_id": "kafka-connect-02:8083"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "state": "RUNNING",
          "worker_id": "kafka-connect-01:8083"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "state": "RUNNING",
          "worker_id": "kafka-connect-03:8083"
        },
```

I don't believe there's a REST API call to view the workers in the cluster regardless of connector execution.

You could parse the Kafka Connect worker logs in the cluster to determine when workers leave and join the cluster, and also inspect the Kafka Connect status topic's messages - both are shown [in this doc](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/connect-cluster/readme.adoc). However, as noted, Kafka Connect itself will do the rebalancing when a workers leaves or joins.